# How to write a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables: `headeritems` and `lineitems`.

HeaderItems table as follows:

[image]

Lineitems table

[image]

Primary key of header items : SrNo,Prefix,TicketNo and Notification
Primary key of line items: SubSrNo,Prefix,TicketNo,NotificationNo

If in header item table serial number flag contains 'X' then there will will entry in lineItems table depending on Required Qty field i.e. if required qty contains 2 then there will be 2 entries in `Lineitems` table.

Now I want to create view which give me output as follows:

```
Notification   Raw material   Serial number 
-------------------------------------------
34186          68
34186          4110           345345
34186          4110           534557
```

This Serial number field not there in header items it is present in line items only.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Notification, [Raw material], [Serial number]
FROM (
    SELECT Notification, [Raw material], NULL [Serial number], 1 ord
    FROM HeaderItems
    WHERE Notification = ...
  UNION
    SELECT Notification, [Raw material], [Serial number], 2 ord
    FROM Lineitems
    WHERE Notification = ...
)
ORDER BY Notification, ord, [Raw material], [Serial number]
```

What this does is combine the two tables (the `UNION`), while adding an extra column used only to sort and make sure headeritems show up above lineitems.

Answer (score 0):

Read about JOIN's.

```
CREARE VIEW vwNotification
AS
SELECT HI.Notification, HI.Raw material, LI.Serial_number
FROM HeaderItems HI 
     LEFT JOIN LineItems LI ON HI.Notification=LI.Notification_No 
                               and HI.Raw_material=HL.Raw_material
ORDER BY HI.Notification, HI.Raw material, LI.Serial_number
```

Comment: Why not? I don't see any reason for that.

Comment: `Raw_material` looks like different data types in each table. Safer I think to join on the primary keys `(SrNo, Prefix,T icketNo, Notification_No)`